# Track which events in a list have been raised

Tags: c#, list, events

I have a list of EventHandlers: `private List<EventHandler> eventHandlers;`

I don't know what this list will contain or how big it will be, but I need to trigger another event once each event in this list has been raised at least once.

Is there a way to do this?

I have looked into subscribing to each event with a lambda expression or an anonymous function and passing a bool from another list that can be marked as True once the event has been raised, but I don't want to lose the ability to unsubscribe from this event later.

Comment: I'm not sure what the intention is, but `EventHandler` in this case is just a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-8.0). If you use "multi cast delegates", i.e. `+=` syntax, you really need to know what you are doing. It was a long time I read about it, but I know the behavior was not at all intuitive for me. You may want to reconsider your approach for whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: It may help to think of MultiCastDelgates as an immutable single linked lists. `+=` will produce a new list with the delegate added, and assigning the variable to the new list. This tend to work fine when used as regular events, i.e. with the `event` keyword, but you need to be really careful when handling them as objects or in lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track the raised events in a `HashSet<T>`. This has the advantage that elements are added only once to the set. Once the hash set has the same number of elements as the list of events, every event has been raised at least once.

```cs
private List<EventHandler> eventHandlers;
private readonly HashSet<EventHandler> raisedHandlers = new();

// Example of an event handler
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: do some work...
    CheckCompleted(Button1_Click);
}

private void CheckCompleted(EventHandler handler)
{
    raisedHandlers.Add(handler);
    if (raisedHandlers.Count == eventHandlers.Count) {
        CompletedEvent?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. The HashSet use also streamlines the rest of the logic, which is great.